# extracting byte ranges in pcap file

Tags: linux, parsing, csv, pcap, tshark

I have written a code in C implementing a protocol and now I want to take out some fields of data from packet of that protocol. I have generated .pcap file, but the data section of packet, there are no defined fields.. but I know which location bits I am intested in..
I want to parse using tshark and take out selected byte ranges and make a .csv and later analyse that csv file.

Eg. in AAA data there are defined fileds, and by using -e the bytes in those fileds can be extracted.

The current packet structure that I have have like 758 bytes in data section and no filed. Is there any way I can extract certain byte ranges ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you really want to do, but if I guess correctly, here is an example to extract range offsets [100,149] from the data section (ie. 50 bytes starting from the 101th byte of the data section, not the packet start)

```
$ tshark -r input.pcap -R "frame.number == 1" -T fields -e data | tr -d '\n' | \
perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' | dd bs=1 skip=100 count=50 of=output.raw
```